# varying efficiency in MILP approach in python

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, python, gurobi

I'm using gurobi in an python enviroment and would like to Model a varying efficiency for a Battery charge/discharge without the Model losing it's MIPL characteristics.

**Example Code:**

```
eta_Batt = 0.9     # Battery Efficiency

E_Batt_StandBy = 0   # Constant Dischsarge in [W]

 

m = Model()

m.setParam("MIPGap", 0.1)

 

x_E_Batt_discharge  = m.addVars(Horizont, name="x_E_Batt_discharge" ,vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS, lb = 0, ub = E_Batt_discharge_max)

x_E_Batt_charge     = m.addVars(Horizont, name="x_E_Batt_charge"    ,vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS, lb = 0, ub = E_Batt_charge_max)

 

m.addConstrs(x_SoC_Batt[t]   == x_SoC_Batt[t-1] + (x_E_Batt_charge[t] * eta_Batt - x_E_Batt_discharge[t] / eta_Batt - E_Batt_StandBy)  * (100* (delta_t/60) / Cap_Batt)  for t in T1)

m.addConstrs(x_SoC_Batt[t]   == SoC_Batt_start + (x_E_Batt_charge[t] * eta_Batt - x_E_Batt_discharge[t] / eta_Batt - E_Batt_StandBy)  * (100* (delta_t/60) / Cap_Batt)  for t in range(1))
```

I'm searching for a way so that eta_Batt is not a constant but decreases with x_E_Batt_charge or x_E_Batt_discharge without having it directly dependent on these variables and therefore making the contrstaints quadratic.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Could you provide a description of your problem (rather than code) ?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but this looks like a MILP to me, no?

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding so quickly 
Yes it's an MILP approach right now, but I want to change the eta_Batt constant so that it changes with the amount of energy that is charged or discharged into the Battery. So eta_Batt needs to be dependent on current E_Batt_charge/discharge without making the last two constraints quadratic.
Hope that's clarifying my problem

Comment: @JohannaSchoofs, suppose the problem has been quadratic. What's happened? Many of the quadratic programs can be linearized.

Comment: Yeah that's true but then the optimizer takes a very long time to solve the problem. I want to avoid that because I want to simulate a hole year in a rolling simulation.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to quadratic constraints to would be to replace x_E_Batt_charge[t] * eta_Batt with a new variable z[t] and define z[t] as a piecewise linear function of x_E_Batt_charge[t]. Recent versions of Gurobi provide support for piecewise linear constraints.

Comment: So simple but it works. Thank you!